# Probability My Opponent Has a Specific Scrabble Letter Mid-Game

Tags: probability

How does one calculate the probability that an opponent would have a specific letter mid-game?

For example: my opponent would have to have a T in his rack in order to hit the Triple Word Score off the word I am considering playing. There are 50 tiles still in the bank (so, that doesn't include the 7 tiles currently on each of our racks.) There are 7 Ts total in the game (I'm actually playing Words With Friends), 2 Ts have been used on the board and I have 1 T in my rack, leaving 4 Ts unaccounted for. So how would I approach calculating the odds that my opponent currently has 1 or more of the remaining 4 Ts on his rack?

Thank you!!!

Comment: I hope you can clear your bench!

Comment: The answers given assume that the contents of your opponent's rack are random. Strictly speaking, this isn't really true unless your opponent cleared their rack on their last turn. To give a fully correct answer to this question, you need to know a lot about your opponent's strategy...

Answer (score 7):

I don't think you can get a definite probability out of that without some very strong assumptions about your opponent's playing style.

The other answers basically assume that the tiles you can't see are distributed *randomly* between the bank and your opponent's rack. This assumption doesn't seem to be warranted here -- which tiles your opponent *holds* will depend to some degree on which ones he prefers to *play*.

Suppose, for example, that your opponent follows a strict strategy of holding on to any T tile he gets until he can hit that particular triple-word field with it. (I grant you that's a somewhat strange strategy, but it's possible within the rules of the game). In that case, if any of the Ts currently on the board were played by your opponent, he'll have another one ready with probability 1.

Even if you don't remember who played what, an opponent who tends to hold on to his T's will be more likely to have one than an opponent who doesn't like holding T's and attempts to play them as soon as he can.

And then there's the question of how many *chances* to play a T your opponent has had (and recognized) recently, which your description of the state of the game doesn't say anything about at all ...

Comment: If I could post a photo of the board I would, but I didn’t care as much about the game as I did about realizing I didn’t know how to approach the problem I created for myself from it - someday I hope to become a math teacher and I want to incorporate games into the classroom as much as possible!

Comment: Whilst that is true, the OP's question did ask about the probability of the possession of a T.  This entails no assumption about the opponent's play.  OP did not ask the odds of the T being actually played, as the opponent might have a bench-clearer elsewhere on the board and he'd likely prefer that.

Comment: @Jane: The unknown state of the board is not the real problem, just some icing on top. What's important is that the opponent has had chances to make strategic decisions that influence the probability, and his strategy is _unknown but not random_. This is not an uncommon situation to end up in: We have a nice pretty _model_ of the world that we can calculate things about, but we _don't know_ how well that model matches reality. Dealing with those situations is arguably a much better learning experience (for you or your eventual students) than any particular computation method.

Comment: @ncmathsadist: The probability the the opponent holds a T _now_ certainly depends on how likely the opponent would have been to play a T if he had one in the _previous_ turns. That does need an assumption about the opponent's playing style.

Answer (score 3):

There are 57 tiles unbeknownst to you, seven on your opponent's bench and 50 in the boneyard.  There are 4 "loose" Ts.
$$P(\hbox{oppponent has > 0 Ts}) = 1 - P(\hbox{ opponent has no Ts}).$$
The opponent has 7 tiles. There are ${57\choose 7}$ possible holding of tiles for him and ${53\choose 7}$ that are T-less. Can you do the rest?

Comment: So, would it be 1- (53/57)^7 = about 40%?

Comment: The other answer completed the calculation.  About 40% is right.

Comment: I care more about the approach than the right answer, is multiplying the probability of T-less tiles times itself 7 times a valid approach or did I just get lucky that it happened to be close?!

Comment: At this stage, you use a little accuracy. But it's easy to get into dangerous waters. Since the calculation is simple, you should unroll the binomials.

Comment: Thank you, I completely forgot how to work with binomials, but I will start searching online now to re-learn them :)

Answer (score 2):

There are $50+7=57$ letters whose place is unknown to you at the moment (they might be in the bank, they might be in his rack), out of which $4$ are "interesting" and you know he has $7$ letters in his rack.

The binomial coefficient $\binom{57}{7}$ tells you the total number of possible racks he can have (you "choose" $7$ out of $57$ tiles). Out of these, $\binom{53}{7}$ are good for you; they don't put any of the "interesting" letters in his rack. The ratio of these two quantities is the probability that he has no "interesting" letter at all in the rack; and if you subtract it from $1$, you'll get the probability he has at least one.

Putting it together and evaluating yields $$\frac{\binom{53}{7}}{\binom{57}{7}}=\frac{53.52.51.50.49.48.47}{57.56.55.54.53.52.51}=\frac{50.49.48.47}{57.56.55.54}\approx 58\%$$
So, he has about $42\%$ chance of having at least one T in the rack.